# Why isn't Pirate Seas unlocking in pvz2?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

I have completed all 25 levels and even got the achievement for completing Ancient Egypt, but still haven't unlocked Pirate Seas. Any solutions?

Comment: You should have obtained a world key, or a pirate seas key, depending on your version. Did you?

Comment: @ pinckerman Nope, i didn't get any key or anything.